# JDA multiple listener

Tags: java, discord, discord-jda

I am trying to make a Discord Bot with JDA(Java Discord API) and I want to do a quiz command that sends the question with the options and some reactions(eg. 1,2,3,4 emojis). Till here everything ok, but the problem comes when I want a user to react to the question as a mean to answer to it, I understand that it is a GenericMessageReactionEvent type to get the reaction but I am using GuildMessageReceivedEvent to process any command and I want to ask if I use an Override, on onMessageReactionAdd, inside the quiz class it will know when someone reacts to the question or do I have to make a special class which extends ListenerAdapter only for it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand from your question you would be able to use the onMessageReactionAdd event to know when someone reacts to a message.
[Here is the documentation for onMessageReactionAdd](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/events/message/react/MessageReactionAddEvent.html)
I assume that you already have a class that extends ListenerAdapter as the GuildMessageReceivedEvent is part of it.
Although if you're not already using ListenerAdapter in your bot, then you would need to extend that in the class that processes commands. If you are already using ListenerAdapter then this will work(and you can add/override all the event methods in your class, you wouldn't have to have two different ListenerAdapter classes)

Comment: Yeah, but the problem comes when i want to call the function cause i don't have an ReactionEvent like event to pass to the function and  i don't know how to retrieve it.

Comment: I don't really know what you mean by this, maybe try adding code to your answer for clarification. If you are trying to wait for a response from _within_ the onMessageReceived event, then I don't think this is possible, the way I solved this was pretty difficult, and basically included stopping the thread, and the notifiying it when the message was reacted to. Not a great solution, maybe someone else would know more about this

Comment: I changed the way i did it. Instead using reactions for answer i did it with text message and wait for an answer within x seconds. Anyway, thanks for the help!